# Akka Http web app fails to pass health check in Amazon ECS

Tags: scala, docker, amazon-ecs, akka-http, docker-network

**UPDATE**

### Answered by myself

So I trying to deploy my dockerized Akka Http sample app into Amazon Elastic Container Service. I'm using sbt Docker Plugin to simplify image creation.

**Problem:** And my app in docker works fine locally but not in EC2 instance when launched by auto-scaling group. For some reason exposed port is not accessible. Thus health check becomes "Unhealthy" and container gets killed in 15 seconds after start.

**What I tried:**

1. CloudWatch logs contained normal start logs:

> Server online at http://0.0.0.0:4567/

2. I visited EC2 instance and tried to curl the container when it was started by agent. Result was:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 4567: Connection refused

3. I ran docker container manually in EC2. Port only works when I run it with `-p 4567:4567`. But I run **network mode "host"** and I believe that port mapping is not required. ECS Agent doesn't use port mapping during container start (observable in `docker ps`).
4. I tried to deploy both host address bindings:

   `Http().bindAndHandle(routes, "localhost", 4567) // doesn't work locally on Mac`

   `Http().bindAndHandle(routes, "0.0.0.0", 4567)   // works locally in Docker`
5. I tested with another docker image for comparison and it worked perfectly (`tongueroo/sinatra:latest`): I was able to curl it in EC2 and it passed health check.
6. ECS agent doesn't show anything useful from my point of view.

I guess something goes wrong with EXPORT 4567 or scala/java binding to port. What are your ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared to be my own fault with Scala code I copy pasted from somewhere.

OLD code which doesn't work in ECS env, but seamlessly works locally! :

```
val serverBinding: Future[Http.ServerBinding] = Http().bindAndHandle(routes, "0.0.0.0", 4567)

  serverBinding.onComplete {
    case Success(bound) =>
      println(s"Server online at http://${bound.localAddress.getHostString}:${bound.localAddress.getPort}/")
      StdIn.readLine() // let it run until user presses return
      serverBinding
        .flatMap(_.unbind()) // trigger unbinding from the port
        .onComplete(_ => system.terminate()) // and shutdown when done
    case Failure(e) =>
      Console.err.println(s"Server could not start!")
      e.printStackTrace()
      system.terminate()
  }
```

NEW fixed code which works:

```
  val serverBinding: Future[Http.ServerBinding] = Http().bindAndHandle(routes, "0.0.0.0", 4567)

  serverBinding.onComplete {
    case Success(bound) =>
      println(s"Server online at http://${bound.localAddress.getHostString}:${bound.localAddress.getPort}/ v8")
    case Failure(e) =>
      Console.err.println(s"Server could not start!")
      e.printStackTrace()
      system.terminate()

  println("Waiting for termination...")
  Await.result(system.whenTerminated, Duration.Inf)
  println("TERMINATED")
```

There were not blocking action and JVM exited quickly after binding happened.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you're fine.

Did you configure your task definition to bind the port ? It's very important because if you don't expose the app port you can't do anything.

[image: ECS port mapping]

And then if you want to execute an HTTP request from your machine to the container you will need to use an Service Discover. AWS now offers you a Service discover through Route 53. But you can use CONSUL and Fabio.

Comment: I embraced to tell but it was my pure programming error.